# Why don't people use try-finally to call pygame.quit() in pygame programs?

Tags: pygame

I've seen several games made in Pygame, and none of them uses `try`/`finally` to call `pygame.quit()` when it finishes.

Instead of writing:

```
def main():
    pygame.init()
    try:
        ...
    finally:
        pygame.quit()
```

and using `sys.exit()` to quit, if there are multiple functions implementing different stages of the game (such as the menu and the actual game) with an event loop in each, at least one of them writes:

```
def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

and uses the `terminate()` function to quit. This means that cleanup is not done if there was an error in the program unless the code that may cause the error calls `pygame.quit()` if the error condition is met.

In a game I'm making, there is a part that raises an error if the level is specified incorrectly; this shouldn't happen if the user runs it normally, but I use it when making levels. (Currently, there is no easy level editor, and the level format is a bit tedious to work with: the file just specifies the name of each tile and their neighbours, so it's easy to get a file where there's incorrect connectivity or vertex singularity; however, implementing a better file format seems like more work that it's worth to me.) In this case, to quit correctly, I probably have to write `pygame.quit()` before each raise, but `try`/`finally` should take care of it.

I tried braving that, but couldn't find anything mentioning both `pygame.quit()` and `try`/`finally`.